# Mapbox Distances with Python

Tags: python, mapbox, http-status-code-403

I am trying to calculate distances among given points with Mapbox in Python. I read the documentation and some examples and I came up with the following code.

```
from mapbox import Distance

glinavos = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'properties': {'name': 'glinavos'},
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [39.754598, 20.654121]}}
zoinos = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'properties': {'name': 'zoinos'},
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [39.754204, 20.640761]}}
katogi = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'properties': {'name': 'katogi'},
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [39.776992, 21.180688]}}
myDistance = Distance(access_token="pk.eyJ1IjoiaWxpdHNlIiwiYSI6ImNpenZmcm11YjAwMGQyd2x1Nm9nd2pqcGUifQ.1PZaOWTVajnQZGeBb_x1Bw")
result=myDistance.distances([glinavos,zoinos,katogi], 'driving')
```

It keeps returning a 403 error while everything else seems fine. The three test points are real places and I have tried with two access tokens: my public and my secret (more privileges) one. In addition, I have tried calling the service with the same points and tokens through curl and it worked fine. What is wrong with my script?  In the code above I use the public token.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.
I took reference from : https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py/blob/master/docs/distance.md

Comment: response.content is :

b'{"message":"This API currently is in preview. Please contact us at https://mapbox.com/contact/ to get access.","code":"Forbidden"}'